# Getting the value of TextField from one class to another with button

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm working on getting the value of a textfield from another class using Vaadin.

my solution is something like this.

```
public class MyTextField{

    String str;

    public MyTextField(){
        TextField text = new TextField();
        str = text.getValue().toString();
    }

    public String getStr(){
        return str;
    }    
}

public class MyButton{    
    public MyButton(){
        Button button = new Button("UPDATE");
        button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener(){
            @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                MyTextField text = new MyTextField();
                System.out.println(text.getStr());   
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

the problem is, I always get null result. any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hey, you will get null because you have not initialized the text field with some value.

Comment: @Patton: forgot to put a value for my example, sorry about that.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do some thing like this, to achieve what you are doing. This is based on the assumption that you are trying to read the user entered value on click of a button.
There are two option to achieve this.

### Option 1

```
     public class MyTextField extends TextField{


        public MyTextField(){
        }

        public String getStr(){
            return this.getValue();
        }
    }


    public class MyButton extends Button{

        public MyButton(){
        setCaption("UPDATE");
        }
    }

   //Add in your presentation logic

   final MyTextField text = new MyTextField();
    MyButton button = new MyButton();
    mainLayout.addComponent(text);
    mainLayout.addComponent(button);
    button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println(text.getStr());
        }
    });
```

### Option 2

```
public  class MyTextField extends TextField{


    public MyTextField(){
    }

    public String getStr(){
        return this.getValue();
    }
}


public class MyButton extends Button{

    public MyButton(final MyTextField text){
    setCaption("UPDATE");
    addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                System.out.println(text.getStr());
            }
       });
    }
}
//And in your presentation logic 

    final MyTextField text = new MyTextField();
    MyButton button = new MyButton(text);
    mainLayout.addComponent(text);
    mainLayout.addComponent(button);
```

Please let me know if in case if this is not what you are expecting.

And Kudos to **Hovercraft Full Of Eels** for trying to help him out

Thanks.

Comment: I did try your solution and it works. will this approach works as well with multiple textfield?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple text fields? are you trying to say that you have multiple instance of text fields? if that is what you intended YES! The same approach works

Comment: just a single instance with multiple textfield.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying can you please give me an example

Comment: sorry for my very late response, I was out of town for a week from a family vacation. what I was saying was, for a single instance I have multiple textfields like text1 = new TextField(); and text2 = new TextField(); etc...

Answer (score 4):

In all likelihood the MyTextField object inside of your buttonClick method is not the same MyTextField that is being displayed to the user. A solution is to get a reference to the class that holds the displayed MyTextField, and then call a public method on that reference to extract the text.

---

**Edit 1**
Note that I'm not familiar with Vaadin, but your MyTextField class looks suspicious in that you're **declaring** the TextField *inside* of the constructor making it visible **only** in the constructor. I'm also not sure what calling `getValue()` on it immediately and before any event, before the user's had a chance to interact with the component, will do. This looks very suspicious to me.

---

**Edit 2**

For instance, if this were Swing, I'd do something like:

```
public class MyTextField{

    TextField textField = new TextField();

    public MyTextField(){
    }

    // so it can be added to the gui
    public TextField getTextField() {
      return textField;
    }


    public String getStr(){
        return textField.getValue().toString(); // not sure if this is correct
    }    
}

public class MyButton{  
   private MyTextField textField;
   private Button button = new Button("UPDATE");

   public MyButton(final MyTextField textField){
      this.textField = textField;
      button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println(textField.getStr());   
         }
      });
    }    
}
```

---

**Edit 3**
You ask:

> you have declared "private MyTextField textfield" as a field and add a parameter (MyTextField textfield) from the MyButton constructor. does it mean that I have to pass the class MyTextField to the MyButton class as a reference?

Again, note that I am not familiar with Vaadin, but I am familiar with general use of Java objects, and this I know. If you want to have one class (here MyButton) get the state of another object (here MyTextField), then the first object needs a **valid reference** to the second. One way to get this reference is by passing it in as a constructor parameter. Another is via a setter method, say by giving MyButton a `setMyTextField(TextField textField)` method, and then assigning the reference to your field. Another option is via "dependency injection", but I think that this may be a little too advanced for now, but do consider it in the future.

If you try to do it as you're doing it in your original post, things will likely fail, since sure, you're giving MyButton a MyTextField object, but **what** MyTextField object is this? It's one that has been created in the MyButton class and is present no where else.

Comment: @garagumo: it's really simple. You are creating a new MyTextField inside of buttonClick. Understand that this object has absolutely no relationship to any other MyTextField objects. It cannot magically get the text held by the MyTextField object that is displayed. I'm not sure how to explain this any clearer.

Comment: @LajosArpad: thanks, but if you know Vaadin, then *please* post an answer.

Comment: since the textfield was used as a class variable, is it still necesarry to put a paramater (MyTextField textfield) from the MyButton constructor?

Comment: @garagumo: please clarify your question -- I'm not sure what you're asking. For instance, in your code, TextField is not a field or "class variable" but rather is declared in your constructor.

Comment: you have declared "private MyTextField textfield" as a field and add a parameter (MyTextField textfield) from the MyButton constructor. does it mean that I have to pass the class MyTextField to the MyButton class as a reference?

Comment: @garagumo: please see latest edit. Also, just for my education, can you tell me how far along in your Java education you are. This may have some bearing on how it would be best to explain things to you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, nope, I am not familiar with Vaadin and was thinking to write an answer like you did. So, I just wanted to support your nice gesture.

Comment: I've been doing java for 2 years as a part-time, self taught. mostly my projects are not that complicated until recently, which requires strong OOP concept. reason that I posted the code as simple as possible not only to get the idea from Vaadin programmers but from other as well, since I think that this is a general concept of OOP and not only refers to a specific framework.

Comment: @garagumo: OK, then what I'm saying shouldn't be new to you, as you've undoubtedly used getters/setters, and understand the concept behind references and such. Again I must warn that I have absolutely no knowledge of Vaadin or whether my post applies to Vaadin projects. Let's wait to see if someone more knowledgeable in this library can add to your answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: thank you for spending some of your time in providing me solutions to my post. really appreciate it. best regards,

Comment: +1 for trying to help out. @HovercraftFullOfEels Pls check my answer in Vaadin

Comment: @Patton: thanks, and likewise 1+ for coming in with a Vaadin solution.